# What is my Atom's architecture doing?

Tags: intel-atom, architecture

The short answer is that it's a dual core 64 bit processor at least in my case with a 330. But the Atom's architecture has traits of x64 and x86. So, what is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Atom 330](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Atom) operates as [x86-64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64) thus making it fully backwards compatible with 32 bit code.

Comment: I've read the Wiki page on it and I don't understand -- how is this different than another 64 bit CPU running 32 bit code or even an entire OS as most OEMs do by default?

Comment: @aesthetic priest Such as which CPU?

Comment: x86-64 has elements from both architectures, what is the significant difference between my Phenom running 32 bit Firefox and my Atom doing the same?

Comment: @aesthetic priest Both the Phenom and the Atom are x86-64. Both will operate on the 32 bit instruction set when 32 bit code is being ran. The differences exist in the instruction set; however architecturally speaking (x86-64) they are the same.